# How do I pickle/save my whole procedures of imputation?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, pipeline

I wrote multiple steps to impute a dataset, and I want to pickle/save these steps so that it can be loaded and used automatically when analyzing a new sample.

The steps I did for imputation are:

```
imputer = MissForest()
imputed_data = imputer.fit_transform(data)
imputed_data = pd.DataFrame(imputed_data, columns=data.columns)

#Drop 'id'
imputed_data_initial = imputed_data.drop('id', axis = 1)

#Get unique values
def get_unique_values(col_name):
    return data[col_name].dropna().unique().tolist()

#Find closest distance
def find_closest_value(target, unique_values):
    chosen = unique_values[0]
    L2 = (target - chosen) ** 2
    for value in unique_values:
        if (target - value) ** 2 < L2:
            chosen = value
            L2 = (target - chosen) ** 2
    return chosen

#Imputation
for col_name in columns_name_lst:
    columns_name_lst = imputed_data.columns
    row_count = len(imputed_data)
    unique_values = get_unique_values(col_name)
    if len(unique_values) < 2000:
        for i in range(row_count):
            target = imputed_data.iloc[i][col_name]
            imputed_data.iloc[i][col_name] = find_closest_value(target, unique_values)
```

I want to pickle all these steps as a whole. What're ways I can do in python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn.pipline.Pipeline. Make a list and pass each step as a tuple. Description here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Saving your pipeline could be a bit difficult though. Please check this question: [how to save a scikit-learn pipline with keras regressor inside to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984304/how-to-save-a-scikit-learn-pipline-with-keras-regressor-inside-to-disk)